# Slickgrid html entities problem in Editor

Tags: php, javascript, slickgrid

i am using slickgrid (js grid) to display some data. because i need to put the data inside " and my content contains programming code, i decode the content with the php function htmlentities($mycontent,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8").

Now everything renders fine EXCEPT If i edit the cell. then it does not display "ä" but &_auml; (i used the _to prevent rendering). i want it to be displayed like the normal view.

normal view:
[image]

edit view:
[image]

i also went into the code ->slickeditor.js to do a html entity decode (manually written) in js but without success.

is there an intelligent solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try change your server ServerDefaultCharset and apply your country charset, this will avoid the usage of htmlentities.

You may create a .htacces with this rule:

```
ServerDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Now you do not encode the html as entities.

I hope it give you a help, it help me at other similar situations, as my language is Portuguese with the same difficulty as yours.

Comment: thx for your answer. the problem in my case is not related to utf-8 but to html entities since it strips all signs like ><"'; etc..